# iOS universal links (applinks) not working for subdomains

Tags: ios, subdomain, applinks

Having an issue filtering allowed subdomains for my app's universal links.

Let's say i have those domains:

```
 - a.subdomain.domain.com 
 - b.subdomain.domain.com 
 - c.subdomain.domain.com
```

I want my app to be opened by `a.subdomain.domain.com` and `b.subdomain.domain.com` but not `c.subdomain.domain.com`.

As i understood it's not possible to exclude a subdomain in the association file hosted on the server, only path for that domain (with the "NOT /xxx/" in paths).

So went with the choice of allowing a list of subdomains instead of excluding one.

But it doesn't work as expected..

I uploaded association file on both `a.subdomain.domain.com` and `b.subdomain.domain.com`. Even on `subdomain.domain.com`.
AASA file contains `"paths": ["*"]`

In my app entitlements i specified `"applinks:a.subdomain.domain.com"` and `"applinks:b.subdomain.domain.com"`

Doesn't open anything. Feels like when i'm adding more than the domain itself in the entitlements it stops working completely.

`"applinks:*.domain.com"` is fine but opens all the subdomains.

`"applinks:a.subdomain.domain.com"`, `"applinks:*a.subdomain.domain.com"` or even `"applinks:*.subdomain.domain.com"` breaks everything.

An i missing something? Haven't found anything about subdomain not being allowed in entitlements, the way it's explained in the [official Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) it should be working...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess no one have interest in that, so i will answer myself after finding out the way, maybe it will be useful to someone else later.

The association file have to be present on both `subdomain.domain.com` and `domain.com` for `"applinks:*.subdomain.domain.com"` to be working.

If you want to limit to `"applinks:a.subdomain.domain.com"` and `"applinks:b.subdomain.domain.com"`, the file have to ALSO be present in `a.subdomain.domain.com` and `b.subdomain.domain.com` or any other subdomain you will explicitly specify in the app entitlements.

Very poorly documented by apple for such an important feature.

Comment: This still doesnt work for us, have the association files on every domain